# How to use a table as a drawing grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html-table

I am trying to create a table with ~10,000 cells and turn this into a canvas on which the user can draw with mouse movements.

I would like to be able to draw on the canvas by highlighting the background of cells the mouse moves over when holding certain keys (blue = ctrl, red = shift, etc).

I have generated my HTML code but I am having trouble with the table. It seems that it is trying to select table cells instead of coloring in the cells.

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image]

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Drawing Program</title>
<h1>Drawing Demonstration</h1>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
<script src = "draw.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id = "canvas">
  <caption>Hold Ctrl (or Control) to draw in blue.
    Hold Shift to draw in red.</caption>
    <tbody id = "tablebody"></tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
table{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
width: 4px;
height: 4px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function createCanvas()
{
    var side = 100;
    var tbody = document.getElementById( "tablebody" );

for( var i = 0; i < side; i++) 
{
    var row = document.createElement( "tr" );

    for( var j = 0; j < side; j++)
    {
        var cell = document.createElement( "td" );
        row.appendChild( cell );
    }
    tbody.appendChild( row );
}
document.getElementById( "canvas" ).addEventListener( "mousemove", processMouseMove, false );
}

function processMouseMove( e )
{
  if( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "td" )
{
    if( e.ctrlKey )
    {
        e.target.setAttribute( "class", "blue" );
    }
    if ( e.shiftKey )
    {
        e.target.setAttribute( "class", "red" );
    }
}
}
window.addEventListener( "load", createCanvas, false );
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making ten thousand table cells, I recommend that you make a `canvas` element and paint it with pixels that are the size of table cells. You can convert the mouse coordinates into pixel positions with modulo arithmetic.

For example, if the mouse is at (x, y) and each pixel has size 4, the mouse is over the pixel such that:

- row = x - x % 4
- column = y - y % 4

The following snippet demonstrates this approach. When you run the snippet, you'll have to click inside the frame containing the canvas in order to give mouse focus to the frame.

```js
var Paint = {
  pixel: { size: 4 },
  grid: { numRows: 100, numCols: 100 }
};

window.onload = function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('paintCanvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      offset = getOffset(canvas, document.body),
      pixelSize = Paint.pixel.size,
      numRows = Paint.grid.numRows,
      numCols = Paint.grid.numCols,
      painting = false;
  
  canvas.width = numCols * pixelSize;
  canvas.height = numRows * pixelSize;
  
  window.onkeydown = function (event) {
    var code = event.which;
    if (code == 17 || code == 16) {
      painting = true;
      context.fillStyle = (code == 17 ? '#1b6bb5' : '#b53a31');
    }
  };
  
  window.onkeyup = function (event) {
    var code = event.which;
    if (code == 17 || code == 16) {
      painting = false;
    }
  };
  
  canvas.onmousemove = function (event) {
    if (!painting) {
      return;
    }
    event = event || window.event;
    var mouse = getMousePosition(event),
        x = mouse.x - offset.left,
        y = mouse.y - offset.top;
    x -= x % pixelSize;
    y -= y % pixelSize;
    context.fillRect(x, y, pixelSize, pixelSize);
  };
};
  
function getOffset(element, ancestor) { 
  var left = 0,
      top = 0;
  while (element != ancestor) { 
    left += element.offsetLeft;
    top += element.offsetTop;
    element = element.parentNode;
  } 
  return { left: left, top: top };
} 

function getMousePosition(event) { 
  if (event.pageX !== undefined) { 
    return { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY };
  } 
  return { 
    x: event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + 
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    y: event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + 
        document.documentElement.scrollTop
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

canvas {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p> <b>Click here to start.</b> Hold Ctrl to draw in blue, Shift to draw in red. </p>

<canvas id="paintCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Its about the same approach as my solution but without the table in the background, it a very good answer so for me this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a blank div position absolute in front of the table and read the td height and width to calculate the xy position in the table from the mouse move. and then do the table magic.